# Use http urls with Flutter http during development

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am developing a flutter app with backend running in localhost.

I am using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for making http calls. I am creating the Uri like this:

```
Uri.https("localhost:8080", "api/v1/login");
```

but this `Uri.https` gives error, instead I need to use `Uri.http`.

The problem is when the app is ready for production I will have to manually edit code everywhere to use `Uri.https` instead of `Uri.http`.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Where is your Flutter app running? Of course you can never use localhost if the server is not on the same device as the client.

Comment: `a flutter app with backend running in localhost.` So it is both unclear where you backend would run and your Flutter app as every device or pc or emulator is its own localhost. There are so many ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `kReleaseMode` to detect you are in release mode or not.

```
String baseUrl;

if (kReleaseMode) {
  baseUrl = 'https://example.com';
} else {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
}

Uri uri = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/api/v1/login');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this:

```
 var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/api/v1/login'));
    print(response.body);
  }
```